# Why doesn't Visual Studio 2010 break on an unhandled exception?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, debugging

When there is an exception thrown in my program, and it is unhandled, I expect the debugger to break in my program and show me what the problem is.  This doesn't happen.  Instead, my program simply exits, and debugging stops.

If I look at the debugging output, I can see my exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in System.dll

I am using Visual Studio 2010, Visual Basic, writing a simple WinForms app.  The code doesn't matter in this case... it happens with *any* exception that I've seen so far.

I've read a lot online about doing to the *Debug* menu and clicking *Exceptions* and enabling "break on unhandled user exception", but I don't see this option.  I think this advice is for VS2008, and is no longer applicable.

I should also note that I'm not running any unit tests.  I have never set them up.  However, I have read that perhaps the unit tester is swallowing my exceptions?

Please advise me on how to change the behavior of Visual Studio, so I can track down these unhandled exceptions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: @Cody, no I am using Windows XP SP3, 32 bit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The item may not be in the menu, which you can fix by customising the menu and adding the item to the debug menu.

You should also be able to get to the exceptions menu using CTRL + ALT + E

You need to tick the box in the "Thrown" column for Common Language Runtime exceptions (CLR)

Comment: Thanks Sohnee.  To clarify, I see *Exceptions* on the debug menu, and can pull it up.  All I see though are options for C++, CLR, Manage Debugging Assistants, etc.  Searching for user anything turned up nothing of value.

Comment: You need to tick the box in the "Thrown" column for Common Language Runtime exceptions (CLR). This will ensure you break on all errors. I will add this detail to the answer.

Comment: @Sohnee, that's working now, thanks.  Will this also break on handled exceptions?  If so, is it possible to get it to break only on unhandled exceptions?

Comment: The second column is for unhandled exceptions - it is normally ticked by default... although if you aren't seeing an exception thrown with this option on, you might find that there is a try / catch further up the stack.

Comment: How do you set the *default* settings for which exceptions break on throw?

Comment: Interesting.  My default options have everything unticked.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sohnee, VS is breaking where I expect it to.  However, it is breaking differently than I'd like.  Before when it would break on exception, I could drag the position in my program around, to restart a sub for example.  The exception was highlighted in yellow.  Now it is highlighted in green, and I can't move it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Finally!  I've been looking all over the net for this answer.  Another tip is to "Enable Just My Code" under Tools -> options -> Debugging

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. i opened the exceptions dialog and clicked the "Restore the list to the default settings" button and now it breaks on unhandled exceptions correctly.

there's probably a bug with upgrading from 2013.

Comment: In my case, this was Visual Studio 2010, but good to know it's fixed in later versions.