# C# crash on runtime without exception

Tags: c#, wpf, nullreferenceexception

Ok this have been bugging me long enough now and have tried to Google it so here goes.

This is my code (I know it fails, that's the purpose):

```
public class Example
{
    private List<string> TestModes;

    public Example()
    {
        SetMode();
        TestModes = new List<string>();
    }

    public void SetMode()
    {
        TestModes.Add("This is a test mode");
    }
}
```

Here `TestMode` is `null` when I try to add a test case. What happens next is that the application stops and vanishes without any thrown exception or error of any kind. Am I wrong or shouldn't a NullReferenceException or something similar been thrown?

I use Visual Studio 2013 and have frankly no clue if this is a VS problem, C#/WPF problem or if it's just working as intended.

**EDIT**

1. Forgot to mention that it is running in Debug mode.
2. Everything under Debug -> Exceptions is checked

Comment: How do you start your application, how does it call this code?

Comment: First things to do: are you running in Debug mode, instead of release, did you try restarting VS?

Comment: Running in Debug mode and it's been doing it for the past months so restart does not solve it :-/

Comment: Is this the testcase? http://i.imgur.com/R4lt2Cs.png it "works" on my machine.. as in, it throws the expected exception

Comment: Maybe this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552416/why-doesnt-visual-studio-2010-break-on-an-unhandled-exception

Comment: @RonSijm The code above causes problem when I run it.

Comment: Put in a breakpoint and see what actually happens, maybe the exception is getting caught in a strange place and you just aren't aware of it...

Comment: Tried to do that, everything is stopped and closed when trying to Step Into the TestModes.Add()

Answer (score 3):

This might be related to debugger configuration

In visual studio go to Debug -> Exceptions...

Make sure that all the "User-unhandled" checkboxes are checked.

To make sure you will break when the exception is thrown you could also check the box at Common Language Runtime Exceptions | Thrown

Hope this helps.

Comment: All User-unhandled are checked (although some of the checkboxes are checked but greyed out) also tried to check all Thrown boxes but still crash without messages.

Comment: And you are sure the debugger is properly attached? 
so normal breakpoints work as expected?

Comment: Yes, tried to place a breakpoint a couple of lines above the crashing one and I'm able to debug step as normal until I try to step into the Add() call which is when everything shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is that you're not running it in debug mode and it's simply crashing out.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am running in Debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Press **ctrl-alt-e** (or navigate to Debug/Exceptions).

There you can activate CLR exceptions so VStudio will break your code when the exception is either *thrown* or *unhandled*.