# How Do I Run a Visual Studio Macro for All Files of a Certain Type Within a Specific Folder Within a Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros

Visual Studio 2010 macro question:

I have a macro that I can execute within another macro to make changes to .aspx files like so:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Macros.Abba.Module1.AbbaZabba")
```

I would like to be able to do this for all .aspx files within a folder in the solution explorer.

For instance, my solution explorer looks like:

Solution 'YourSolutionName'

-Project 1

--ParentFolder

---ChildFolder

And I want to be able to have this macro run for each .aspx file within the child folder - but no non-aspx files. I have looked for days for ways to do this but nothing seems to work, right now I have to run the macro by hand on each file and this could take a while.

I do not mind putting the folder name in manually, nor do I mind the alternative of selecting a folder before running the macro. I am very much a beginner at coding so referring me to use some method or other is more helpful than nothing, but less helpful than helping me to walk through it a little.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work myself by splicing in two different approaches (one to find the folder and another to iterate through the files).

The one to find the folder I want is here, the toggle triggers macro:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264485(v=vs.80).aspx

The iterate macro is the helpful answer here:

[Need Visual Studio macro to add banner to all C# files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415101/need-visual-studio-macro-to-add-banner-to-all-c-sharp-files)

The final solution:

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module iterateFolder
  Sub IterateFiles(Optional ByVal dbProjName As String = "")
    Dim project As Project
    Dim parentFolder As String = ""
    Dim courseFolder As String = ""

    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbProjName)) Then
        dbProjName = InputBox("Type the database project name.")
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbProjName)) Then
            Return
        End If
    End If

    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(parentFolder)) Then
        parentFolder = InputBox("Type the parent folder name.")
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(parentFolder)) Then
            Return
        End If
    End If

    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(courseFolder)) Then
        courseFolder = InputBox("Type the child folder name.")
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(courseFolder)) Then
            Return
        End If
    End If

    For Each project In DTE.Solution
        Dim projectItem As EnvDTE.ProjectItem
        If (dbProjName.Equals(project.Name)) Then
            For Each projectItem In project.ProjectItems()
                If (projectItem.Name = parentFolder) Then
                    Dim subItem As EnvDTE.ProjectItem
                    For Each subItem In projectItem.ProjectItems()
                        If (subItem.Name = courseFolder) Then
                            IterateProjectFiles(subItem.ProjectItems)
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub IterateProjectFiles(ByVal prjItms As ProjectItems)
    For Each file As ProjectItem In prjItms
        If file.SubProject IsNot Nothing Then
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.SolutionExplorer")
            If file.Name.EndsWith(".aspx") Then
                file.Open()
                file.Document.Activate()
                DTE.ExecuteCommand("Macros.Abba.Module1.AbbaZabba")
            End If
            IterateProjectFiles(file.ProjectItems)
        ElseIf file.ProjectItems IsNot Nothing AndAlso file.ProjectItems.Count > 0 Then
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.SolutionExplorer")
            If file.Name.EndsWith(".aspx") Then
                file.Open()
                file.Document.Activate()
                DTE.ExecuteCommand("Macros.Abba.Module1.AbbaZabba")
            End If
            IterateProjectFiles(file.ProjectItems)
        Else
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.SolutionExplorer")
            If file.Name.EndsWith(".aspx") Then
                file.Open()
                file.Document.Activate()
                DTE.ExecuteCommand("Macros.Abba.Module1.AbbaZabba")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Module
```

You can hard code the project and folder names, or just some of them, or leave them all blank depending on how much versatility you need.

I should note here that the abbazabba macro does the closing and saving of the file, but if this is useful for anyone you can get how to do that from the 2nd link in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 'AddDirAsSlnFolder' example macro that comes with Visual Studio 2010. It looks like it has a lot of the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I had already looked at that and I couldn't pull the relevant parts out and make it work. I did flag this post useful, however.